# images in webview missing after upgrade from titanium to appcelerator

Tags: image, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

After updating from titanium (sdk 3.2.3.GA) to appcelerator (SDK 5.1.2.GA) the images on all local webviews have went missing from the app. The CSS that loads the image is:

```
background-image:url(imgs/images.png)
```

This error appears in my terminal when accessing the webview:

```
[ERROR] Error loading /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/28073F1B-1FFF-459A-BA4A-6CCA9EB85CEB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B337E08-79EF-4EE1-A62F-338E45199403/MyApp.app/webViews/imgs/images.png
```

Again, this was working fine on older versions.

Any advice on what to check to get local images showing in webviews again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've found a regression. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.